# Problem with json-web-token verifying in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, jwt

I'm really confused about the error. I can't figure out what is happening. What I'm trying to do is verifying the token.

```
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");

jwt.verify(token, config.get("jwtSecret"), (err, decoded) => {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err);
    return res.status(401).json({ msg: "Token is not valid" });
  } else {
    console.log(decoded);
    req.user = decoded.user;
    next();
  }
})
```

The error is

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token . in JSON at position 30
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at Object.jwsDecode [as decode] (C:\Users\kira\Desktop\repo\dev_connector\node_modules\jws\lib\verify-stream.js:71:20)
    at module.exports (C:\Users\kira\Desktop\repo\dev_connector\node_modules\jsonwebtoken\decode.js:5:21)
    at Object.module.exports [as verify] (C:\Users\kira\Desktop\repo\dev_connector\node_modules\jsonwebtoken\verify.js:69:20)
    at module.exports (C:\Users\kira\Desktop\repo\dev_connector\middlewares\auth.js:11:7)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\kira\Desktop\repo\dev_connector\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at next (C:\Users\kira\Desktop\repo\dev_connector\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:137:13)
    at Route.dispatch (C:\Users\kira\Desktop\repo\dev_connector\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:112:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\kira\Desktop\repo\dev_connector\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at C:\Users\kira\Desktop\repo\dev_connector\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:281:22
    at Function.process_params (C:\Users\kira\Desktop\repo\dev_connector\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:335:12)
    at next (C:\Users\kira\Desktop\repo\dev_connector\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:275:10)
    at Function.handle (C:\Users\kira\Desktop\repo\dev_connector\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:174:3)
    at router (C:\Users\kira\Desktop\repo\dev_connector\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:47:12)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\kira\Desktop\repo\dev_connector\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at trim_prefix (C:\Users\kira\Desktop\repo\dev_connector\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:317:13)
```

After I tracked down the code, I found the problem in parsing the payload.
When the library parsing the payload, the value of "iat" is not valid. That's where the error comes from. What the library is doing:

```
Buffer.from(payload, 'base64').toString(encoding)
```

What it returns:

```
"{"user":{"id":"userId"},"iat":.��n\���ctLf��x�):�'�8}"
```

But I'm not providing any custom option for the "iat" field. That's what I automatically get from the library.

The token is:

```
eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ1c2VyIjp7ImlkIjoidXNlcklkIn0sImlhdCI6MTU2MjA0NzgzNiwiZXhwIjoxNTYyNDA3ODM2fQ.YCwjwaGV9Jm2u7rmsCe65wKzPTw5jtS38n2tVEGiCUI
```

Comment: You need to share the JSON with us, that is where the error is located.

Comment: It seems like the token you are trying to verify contains invalid JSON, probably in its payload. Unfortunately can't help much more without knowing your token (but don't paste it here if it might contain sensitive data)

Comment: If it contains sensitive data, then you are using Web Tokens wrong.

Comment: Back to topic: I checked the token on http://jwt.io and it looks fine, nothing wrong with the payload.

Comment: Yeah but. There is a problem in verifying the token. And the error comes from parsing the payload. I'm really confused.

Comment: So what you observered hapens inside of `jwt.verify(token...`, right?!  can you place a `consolw.log(token)`directly before the call to `jwt.verify(` and show the output. I assume, you get the token from a http request. Maybe something happens to the token before you call verify.

Comment: @jps I log it and it's the same token.

Comment: sorry, I have no idea anymore. The code you posted looks fine, the token is fine too. Maybe something wrong with your installation. Change to a new diretory and start over with `$ npm install jsonwebtoken`

Comment: @jps I rewrite all over again. The first time I run the code, it works. jwt.io debugger shows that the toke's signature is valid. All good.  Second time, when the code generated a new token, then the same error comes up. And the debugger shows invalid signature. You can see the error  [here] (https://ibb.co/sshMbP9). The iat filed is invalid json.

Comment: Did you make any progress?